# Cant log in with the first time, OnSubmit

Tags: reactjs

I am validating some details, the problem is when the validation is complete and I want to move to the next page with submit. it logs in with the second try

I have tried to put all the validation process to the OnChange function, but it messes up all of the validation process, I have also tried to put the error variables to the state but I receive an error message that It's constant variables and can't be changed.

```
import { Link } from 'react-router-dom';

class Profile extends Component {
  state = {
    details: {
      firstName: '',
      lastName: '',
      id: '',
      email: ''
    },
    error: false,
    complete: false
  };

  OnSubmit = e => {
    e.preventDefault();
    let re = /^(([^<>()\[\]\\.,;:\s@"]+(\.[^<>()\[\]\\.,;:\s@"]+)*)|(".+"))@((\[[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}])|(([a-zA-Z\-0-9]+\.)+[a-zA-Z]{2,}))$/;
    const { email } = this.state.details;
    const { firstName } = this.state.details;
    const { lastName } = this.state.details;
    const { id } = this.state.details;
    let errorid = false;
    let errorfirstlast = false;
    let erroremail = false;

    if (id.length <= 9 && id !== '') {
      console.log('trueid');
      errorid = false;
    } else {
      errorid = true;
      console.log('falseid');
    }

    if (re.test(email)) {
      console.log('trueemail');
      erroremail = false;
    } else {
      erroremail = true;
      console.log('falseemail');
    }

    if (
      firstName !== '' &&
      lastName !== '' &&
      firstName.substr(0, 1) === firstName.substr(0, 1).toUpperCase() &&
      lastName.substr(0, 1) === lastName.substr(0, 1).toUpperCase() &&
      !firstName.match(/\d/) &&
      !lastName.match(/\d/)
    ) {
      console.log('truefirstlast');
      errorfirstlast = false;
    } else {
      errorfirstlast = true;
      console.log('falsefirstlast');
    }
    if (erroremail === true || errorfirstlast === true || errorid === true) {
      this.setState({ error: true });
    } else {
      this.setState({ error: false });
      this.setState({ complete: true });
    }
  };

  OnChange = e => {
    e.preventDefault();
    this.setState({
      details: { ...this.state.details, [e.target.name]: e.target.value }
    });
  };

  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <div className="container text-center mt-4" style={{ width: '500px' }}>
          <form className="px-4 py-3" onSubmit={this.OnSubmit}>
            <div className="form-group">
              {this.state.error === true ? (
                <p className="text-danger">
                  Some of the details are wrong check the fields above
                </p>
              ) : null}
              <label>First Name:</label>
              <input
                type="text"
                className="form-control"
                onChange={this.OnChange}
                name="firstName"
              />
            </div>
            <div className="form-group">
              <label>Last Name:</label>
              <input
                type="text"
                className="form-control"
                onChange={this.OnChange}
                name="lastName"
              />
            </div>
            <div className="form-group">
              <label>ID Number:</label>
              <input
                type="text"
                className="form-control"
                onChange={this.OnChange}
                name="id"
              />
            </div>
            <div className="form-group">
              <label>Email:</label>
              <input
                type="text"
                className="form-control"
                onChange={this.OnChange}
                name="email"
              />
            </div>
            {this.state.complete === true ? (
              <Link to="/success">
                <button type="submit" className="btn btn-secondary mt-3">
                  Check
                </button>
              </Link>
            ) : (
              <button type="submit" className="btn btn-secondary mt-3">
                Check
              </button>
            )}
          </form>
        </div>
      </div>
    );
  }
}

export default Profile;
```

The problem is that I enter the next page with the second click on the submit button, I want to enter with the first try

Comment: Can you refactor your question to explain what your goal is and what parts of the code you're having problems with?

Comment: I want the submit button to work on the first try, when the values are correct.

Answer (score 1):

The reason that routing to the next page only happens on the second click of the Submit button is because the `Link` to the next page is only rendered after `this.state.complete` is `true`, which only happens after hitting submit for the first time.

In other words, the flow you have currently is:

- Fill in form, when done, hit the "Check" button
- Hitting the "Check" button triggers the `onSubmit` function. If the input data is valid, set the state variable `complete` to `true`.
- Updating state triggers a re-render and now the "Check" button contains the `Link` to the next page.
- Click the "Check" button again, which will click the `Link` and take the user to the next page.

(Note: perhaps the flow would be more clear if you separated the `Link` from the submit button)

If you want the user to be taken to the next page on the *first* click of the "Check" button (if the input data is valid), you can control the routing programmatically inside of the `onSubmit` function, rather than relying on a `Link` to be clicked. This can be done by passing the desired route to `history.push`. In fact, with this method, we can do away with the `complete` state variable entirely (and the `Link` in your render method).

For example:

```js
import { withRouter } from "react-router-dom";

class Profile extends Component {
    onSubmit = e => {
        // ... validation
        if (erroremail || errorfirstlast || errorid) {
            this.setState({ error: true });
        } else {
            this.props.history.push("/success");
        }
    }
}

export default withRouter(Profile);
```

Note that you'll need to wrap `Profile` in `withRouter` in order to access `this.props.history`.

Also a small code-style note: checking if a boolean is equal to `true` is redundant, since the value itself is already either `true` or `false` (which are the outputs of the `===` operator anyway).

Answer (score 0):

setState is asynchronous, wrapping it in a function call will make it work for you.

```js
if (erroremail === true || errorfirstlast === true || errorid === true) {
      this.setState(() => { error: true });
    } else {
      this.setState(() => { error: false, complete: true });
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I solved this by moving all of the validation to `OnChange` function.

```
    e.preventDefault();
    let re = /^(([^<>()\[\]\\.,;:\s@"]+(\.[^<>()\[\]\\.,;:\s@"]+)*)|(".+"))@((\[[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}])|(([a-zA-Z\-0-9]+\.)+[a-zA-Z]{2,}))$/;
    const details = { ...this.state.details, [e.target.name]: e.target.value };
    this.setState({
      details,
      complete:
        details.id.length <= 9 &&
        details.id !== '' &&
        re.test(details.email) &&
        details.firstName !== '' &&
        details.lastName !== '' &&
        details.firstName.substr(0, 1) ===
          details.firstName.substr(0, 1).toUpperCase() &&
        details.lastName.substr(0, 1) ===
          details.lastName.substr(0, 1).toUpperCase() &&
        !details.firstName.match(/\d/) &&
        !details.lastName.match(/\d/)
    });
```

and only set the error in `submit` .